# Optimise Time Complexity of a function - Kotlin

Tags: algorithm, kotlin, big-o

I have a function below:

```
fun getTimess(time: Array<Int>, direction: Array<Int>): Array<Int> {

    //check for range of values
    if (time.size > 100_000 || direction.size > 100_000) return emptyArray()

    //ensure that direction values are between 0 and 1
    if (direction.max() !in (0..1) || direction.min() !in (0..1)) return emptyArray()

    val result = Array(time.size) { 0 }
    val endTime: Int = time.max() ?: 0

    //check for time range
    if (endTime > 1_000_000_000 || endTime < 0) return emptyArray()


    if (endTime == 0) return result
    val inQueue: Queue<Pair<Int, Int>> = LinkedList()
    val outQueue: Queue<Pair<Int, Int>> = LinkedList()

    var currentTime = 0 //current time

    //indicates who used the turnstile in the previous second,
    // -1 if non used the turnstile in the last sec.
    var turnstile = -1

    for (i in time.indices) {
        if (direction[i] == 1) {
            outQueue.add(Pair(time[i], i))
        } else {
            inQueue.add(Pair(time[i], i))
        }
    }

    while (outQueue.isNotEmpty() || inQueue.isNotEmpty()) {
        //checking fot exit
        if (outQueue.isNotEmpty()
            && outQueue.peek().first <= currentTime
            && (turnstile == 1 || turnstile == -1 || inQueue.isEmpty()
                    || (inQueue.peek().first > currentTime && turnstile == 0))
        ) {
            result[outQueue.poll().second] = currentTime
            turnstile = 1

        } else if (inQueue.isNotEmpty() && inQueue.peek().first <= currentTime) {
            result[inQueue.poll().second] = currentTime
            turnstile = 0
        } else {
            turnstile = -1
        }

        currentTime++
    }

    return result
}
```

It outputs correctly but the issue is that it does not execute within the time limits. How can I possibly optimise the function to execute faster? It only has one for loop and one while loop.

Comment: Well... a linked list add operation is O(n), so your for-loop is O(n^2)...

Comment: @thebjorn how can I optimise it?

Comment: I would diagnose where the bottle neck is first. As @thebjorn points out it could be the linked list, but the while is also a potential bottle neck. Why don't you time the two loops and see which takes the longest time?

Comment: Use a data structure with better add performance? (e.g. ArrayList - I'm not a Kotlin programmer, so someone correct me if I'm wrong).  As @k88 said, profiling before optimizing is the only way to keep sane ;-)

Comment: I will do that and see what it is like

Comment: @thebjorn LinkedList add (without position argument) is O(1)

Comment: @IR42 good to know.

Comment: It seems like you spin round the final loop when both front elements have a time much larger than `currentTime`. Instead, you can just skip `currentTime` ahead to the value where the loop will do something. This makes your final loop O(n) rather than O(n + time.max()).

Comment: @PaulHankin could you explain further what you meant. It is not clear to me. Thanks.

Comment: @JerryOkafor debug by counting iterations of the final loop, and printing when the first, second and third branch of the if statement execute. You will see that `turnstile=-1` is executed MANY times, while `currentTime` slowly counts up to one of the times at the head of the two queues. Better is to set `currentTime` immediately to the min of the times at the head of the two queues immediately in that case, and do `currentTime++` only in the other two cases.

Comment: (It's a tiny bit harder than I write because you have to handle the cases where one or the other queue is empty).